# Initializing vector of vectors in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm trying to create a 2D vector as follows:

```
//create vector of vectors with 7 elements and 4 fields
vector<vector<string>> trainingData(4, vector<string>(7));
vector<string> age;
vector<string> has_job;
vector<string> own_house;
vector<string> credit_rating;

age = {"young", "young", "middle", "middle", "middle", "old", "old"};
has_job = {"no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no"};
own_house = {"no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes"};
credit_rating = {"fair", "good", "fair", "good", "good", "excellent", "good"};

trainingData = {age, has_job, own_house, credit_rating};
```

Is it right to initialize like this? I can list the data according to field names but I cannot delete a vector (e.g. by calling trainingData.erase(trainingData.begin()+1) to delete has_job vector)

Comment: Is this inside a function / class / etc., or just at global scope?

Comment: I initialize inside the main function. The declarations are at global scope.

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot delete a `vector`?  It looks like the statement you listed, `trainingData.erase(trainingData.begin()+1)` should work.  It does not compile, or does not do what you expect at runtime?

Comment: Sorry. It looks like I made a mistake at another part of my code. It works.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Kerrek SB's answer, which addresses the problem at hand.  I think you may want to go further, and make the `training_data` variable vector of structs, rather than a vector-of-vector-of-strings.

```
enum class CreditRating { FAIR, GOOD, EXCELLENT };
enum class Age { YOUNG, MIDDLE, OLD };

// Make plain-old-data, so that you can initialize using aggregate initialization
struct Applicant 
{
  Age age;
  bool has_job;
  bool owns_house;
  CreditRating credit_rating;
};

const std::vector<Applicant> training_data{
        { Age::YOUNG, false, false, CreditRating::FAIR },
        { Age::YOUNG, false, false, CreditRating::GOOD },
        // [...]
        {   Age::OLD, false,  true, CreditRating::GOOD } };

// Use training_data
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks overly clumsy and roundabout. You can *initialize* the vector with the desired content in one go, and even make it const if you like:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> trainingData
  { { "young", "young", "middle", "middle", "middle", "old",       "old"  }
  , { "no",    "no",    "no",     "no",     "yes",    "no",        "no"   }
  , { "no",    "no",    "no",     "no",     "yes",    "yes",       "yes"  }
  , { "fair",  "good",  "fair",   "good",   "good",   "excellent", "good" }
  } ;
```